# Optimize 2 for loops

Tags: c#, optimization

trying to optimize these two for loops... 
GetFileList(string, string)
input parameters
1. adlsPath = ADLS path
2. Prefix = prefix string (comma separated)

```
public List<string> GetFileList(string adlsPath, string prefix)
{
    List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
    List<string> prefixList = prefix.Split(',').ToList();

    if (adlsClient.CheckExists(adlsPath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} - Getting the files in path: {adlsPath}");
        foreach (DirectoryEntry file in adlsClient.EnumerateDirectory(adlsPath))
        {
            if (file.Type == DirectoryEntryType.FILE)
            {
                foreach (string prefixStr in prefixList)
                {
                    if (file.Name.StartsWith(prefixStr))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} - {file.FullName}");
                        fileList.Add(file.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} - The path was not found: {adlsPath}");
        return fileList;
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

======================================

i have changed the for loop like below

```
foreach (string prefixStr in prefixList)
                {
                    IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry> tempFile = adlsClient.EnumerateDirectory(adlsPath).Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith(prefixStr) && f.Type == DirectoryEntryType.FILE);

                    foreach (DirectoryEntry file in tempFile)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("adding file : {0}", file.Name);
                        fileList.Add(file.Name);
                    }
                }
```

but still looking for any other good way

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What's the problem with doing that? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "optimizing", but if you don't mind getting rid of the `Console.WriteLine` lines, you can reduce the method to two lines (a slight difference is that the code below returns an empty list if `prefix` is `null`, which is different than the original method, which throws an exception. This could instead be modified to return all `DirectoryEntryType.FILE` types if `prefix` is `null`, depending on the desired behavior):

```
public List<string> GetFileList(string adlsPath, string prefix)
{
    var prefixes = prefix?.Split(',');

    return prefixes != null && adlsClient.CheckExists(adlsPath)
        ? adlsClient.EnumerateDirectory(adlsPath)
            .Where(file => file.Type == DirectoryEntryType.FILE &&
                           prefixes.Any(prefix => file.Name.StartsWith(prefix)))
            .Select(file => file.Name)
            .ToList()
        : new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: thanks.. this worked for me... only change that i made is 
".Select(file => file.Name).ToList<string>()" 
as above code was giving me error 
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'."

Comment: Thanks, updated the sample

Answer (score 0):

The second loop can be changed. Instead they of checking in array you can use dictionary of prefixes. That will reduce the lookup time.